# jQuery Mobile -Loading data one by one

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've a requirement to design this scenario in jQuery Mobile app.
I have 2 screens a)login b)dashboard home

Dashboard home screen has following components 
a)list box A to show items of type A dynamically and their respective count.
2)List box B to show items of type B dynamically and their respective count.
3)List box C to show fixed 3 items(type C) and their respective count.

each count is overllaped by button to drill down to another screen for further details.

Following Web services are available 
a)Login service to authenticate user and for valid user ,list of type A items and type B items.
b)Count A service to provide count of type A items respectively.
c)count B service to provide count of type B items respectively.
d)count C servive to provide count of type C items respecively.

All services are SOAP based .

When user clicks on login button ,Ajax call is made to invoke Login service and download type A and B items available and store in local storage.
Once data is locally stored ,user is navigated to dashboard screen to show type A and b items without their count.

Now it is required to show respective counts by making count A ,Count B and Count C ajax calls.

I want to know best approach to show dahboard screen in such a way that first items are loaded ,then their counts .after login user should see sashboard screen with items without much wait ,then asynchronously their counts one by one ,in the order count services are called.

I do not want user to wait on login screen after hitting login button untill all services are called and data is available .
I want as and when data is available they should be shown on screen after user is redirected to dashboard.

Please suggest me approach and the way to achieve this .I am beginner in jQuery .please excuse me if this is a naive Q.

Any suggestion would be appreciteted.
Any links ,tutorial,demo for such scenario will also help.

Answer (score 0):

what i get from your Q is you want to load the page without making the user waits until it loads; 
then you probably can use

```
jQuery.mobile.loadPage("wantedpage.html",{options});
```

this function will load the page in the background;

or you can check this : http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html
hope this was a help for you.